# BufferedInputStream's available() not behaving as expected

Tags: java

I'm learning java from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) docs.

I'm learning about `BufferedInputStream`'s `available();`  method right now

I took sample code and worked out following code

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class BufferInput {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      InputStream inStream = null;
      BufferedInputStream bis = null;

      try{
         // open input stream test.txt for reading purpose.
         inStream = new FileInputStream("c:/test.txt");

         // input stream is converted to buffered input stream
         bis = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);      

         // read until a single byte is available
         while( bis.available() > 0 )
         {
            // get the number of bytes available
            Integer nBytes = bis.available();
            System.out.println("Available bytes = " + nBytes );

            // read next available character
            char ch =  (char)bis.read();

            // print the read character.
            System.out.println("The character read = " + ch );
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{

         // releases any system resources associated with the stream
         if(inStream!=null)
            inStream.close();
         if(bis!=null)
            bis.close();
      }
   }
}
```

When I run this code,

It shows following output:

```
Available bytes = 2
The character read = V
Available bytes = 1
The character read = A
```

But in my test.txt file content is SELVA.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `available()` it doesn't do what you think and there's no reason you need it.

Comment: I m practicing one by one contained in BufferInputStream class in io package.. may i know.. why don't use available(); method.. then why it is contained in oracle docs.. thanks..

Comment: Just because a class or a method exists doesn't mean it's necessarily a good idea to use it. Search SO and you'll find plenty of questions with people mistakenly using `available()`. Also, you're planning on trying all of the methods in all classes one by one? I doubt that's a good way to learn programming.

Comment: thanks sir,, may i know, how to learn by best way?... if any your comments will be useful for me.. thanks

Comment: If I knew the best way to learn things, I'd be a millionaire. But you don't learn cooking by first buying a tomato and trying to do everything you can with it, and after that buying a cucumber and so forth... Reading the API is helpful, but there's no information whether using a specific class is considered "up to date". I recommend going through recent tutorials and constantly practicing (and googling). It takes years to become a good programmer.

Comment: your example so nice.. i need to learn only I/O package only.. for that takes years? thanks

Comment: I have no idea why you would "only need to learn I/O package", but this question is becoming less and less fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your code in my eclipse and the output seems to be fine:

```
Available bytes = 5
The character read = s
Available bytes = 4
The character read = e
Available bytes = 3
The character read = l
Available bytes = 2
The character read = v
Available bytes = 1
The character read = a
```